# generating private-public keys using ssh-keygen in unix

Tags: unix

i want to generate a public- private key on sever 1 and store it a location which is not the default location.

then save the public key on server 2 NOT at the default location.

then make this key an authorised key.
i cannot find authorised_keys file in .ssh
how do i make it auhorised.

Answer (score 1):

Either create the file yourself or use `ssh-copy-id` to generate it for you.

Comment: can you elaborate ssh-copy-id

Comment: No, I believe I'll let the man page do so. `man ssh-copy-id`

Comment: i mean where i have to use this command...at which stage

Comment: After you've generated the key, on the machine you've generated it at.

Comment: ssh-copy-id command was not found,but creating the file did the work...thnx